# Power BI- Concatenate text column rows based on unique column key

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Is there a way to Concatenate rows in a text column based on a unique identifier column?

I have created an example of my datainput and the output i want:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you wanted to use powerquery, load the data with table ... from table/range [x] columns

right click UniqueOperationID and Outermessage columns, right click, group, use default options

in the formula bar, change

```
= Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"UniqueOperation ID", "Outermessage"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}})
```

to

```
= Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"UniqueOperation ID", "Outermessage"}, {{"Details", each Text.Combine(List.Transform([Details], Text.From), "#(lf)"), type text}})
```

or if you want commas instead of line breaks use

```
= Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"UniqueOperation ID", "Outermessage"}, {{"Details", each Text.Combine(List.Transform([Details], Text.From), ", "), type text}})
```

file ... close and load ...

In excel, format the column as Wrap Text or you wont see the line breaks

full sample code:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"UniqueOperation ID", Int64.Type}, {"Outermessage", type text}, {"Details", type text}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"UniqueOperation ID", "Outermessage"}, {{"Details", each Text.Combine(List.Transform([Details], Text.From), "#(lf)"), type text}})
in #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]